# Fill a select with a JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I want to fill a selectbox with a JSON value in Spring.

Using @ResponseBody, I have this JSON:

```
[{"id_raza":6,"raza":"Persa"},{"id_raza":7,"raza":"Egipcio"}]
```

I want to set the data in a selectbox such as

```
<option value="6">Persa</option>
<option value="7">Egipcio</option>
```

How can I do it? I see examples with a no-array JSON, but my response is an array.
**Edit:**

The complete code is:

```
$("#clase").change(function () {
    var razaSelected = $("#clase").val();
    alert("Raza Seleccionada: " + razaSelected);
    $.ajax({
       url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/persona/mascotas/raza/" + razaSelected,
       type: 'get',           
       dataType: 'html'
   }).done(function (data) {
       $('#raza').empty();
       data.forEach(function (obj) {
          $('<option />', {value: obj.id_raza, text: obj.raza}).appendTo('#raza');
       });

   });
 });
```

Where `#raza` is the target select and `#clase` is the select to have the change event

When I do `console.log(data)`, I get:

```
"[{"id_raza":6,"raza":"Persa"},{"id_raza":7,"raza":"Egipcio"}]"
```

Many thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, `data` is still JSON so you need to parse it using `JSON.parse`

```
JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(obj){
   $('<option />', { value: obj.id_raza, text: obj.raza }).appendTo('select');
}); // use selector of your choice here involving select here ---------^
```

Comment: In the console I have the error response.forEach is not a function

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados is `response` the Array?

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados do a `console.log(data)` and put that in your question.

Comment: I have "[{"id_raza":6,"raza":"Persa"},{"id_raza":7,"raza":"Egipcio"}]" when I do consele.log(data). I updated the question.

Comment: Yeah! It is correct! Many thanks! I am indebted to you.

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Selector= $("select")
 ajaxread.foreach(function(obj){
 $('<option />', { value: obj.id_raza, text: obj.raza }).appendTo(Selector);
 });
```

then call your method to reinitialize select box

`$(Selector).selectBox();` // or Plugin which you are using